# "You must set either a height or a maxHeight" error with FixedDataTable Component

Tags: javascript, error-handling, reactjs, components

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: You must set either a height or a
>   maxHeight

What does this mean?

Here's the stack:

```
invariant @ invariant.js:39
_calculateState @ FixedDataTable.react.js:669
getInitialState @ FixedDataTable.react.js:305
ReactClass.createClass.Constructor @ ReactClass.js:853
ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:135
ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70
ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38
ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:247
ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70
ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38
ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ ReactMultiChild.js:192
ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ ReactDOMComponent.js:289
```

All I'm trying to do is pull from this [example here](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/site/examples/ObjectDataExample.js).

Comment: hard to tell without the code of your component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're not passing the tableHeight props but it's hard to tell without seeing your component code.